# Button auto width per content but in steps aligned to page grid

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I would like to implement page grid-dependant width buttons so that they have *quasi-auto* width depending on the content, but with certain width steps so that button width always takes N number of page grid columns. When button content becomes too wide to render button in a single grid column, it would then become 2 columns wide (or even more if required)...

This image shows an example how buttons should be sized according to grid:

[image]

First row displays the second button that exceeds single column width (actually it exceeds two columns) and should therefore span 3 columns in the page grid. Second row shows the button correctly sized so it takes 3 full page grid columns.

**How can this be done using only CSS (if at all)?**

> ***Note:*** I know this can be accomplished using Javascript, but I'm looking for a CSS-only solution if possible which may use flex, grid or whatever else layout that CSS3 provides.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the CSS3 property auto-fill and auto-fit. See the Below Link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-columns

Comment: I never considered grid layout which seems to be able provide what I want. I am using flexbox though. but regardless I can't find any **auto-fill** or **auto-fit** on the referred page. It would be great if you could copy the relevant excerpt that you're referring to.

Comment: Please also refer to my additionally attached image to the question, which makes it more clear what I'm trying to accomplish here.